# What is var used for?

Tags: javascript, var

I am confused why you can't just say `name = "Bob"` instead of `var name = "Bob"`. Also, is there a way to set a variable to itself but with some changes.

Such as: `name = name + "and"`

Comment: maybe this should be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0):

From MDN: (Emphasis mine)

> Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.
>
> **Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable** (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Regarding your second point, yes, **you can use the variable you are assigning to in the calculation** as you described. The following code is valid:

```
var test = "foo"
test = test + "bar"
alert(test) // foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

var are containers for storing values, like numbers, objects, strings etc.

**Examples:**

```
var number_variable = 1
var string_variable = ""
var object_variable = {}
var function_variable = function() {
  alert("Hi!")
}
```

Note that executing var inside the function cannot be viewed in global.

**Example:**

```
function myFunc() {
var string = "Hey"
}
myFunc()
console.log(string)
```

It will not log the string "Hey" in the console and will return an error!

**---**

You can combine variables by using +!

**Examples:**

```
var a = "Hey "
var b = "Mom!"
var c = a + b // Hey Mom!
var d = 1
var e = 2
var f = d + e // 3
var g = a + d // Hey 1
var h = e - d // 1
var i = 4 / e // 2
var j = 3 * e // 6
```